# Stack Exchange API : get post list from user

Tags: javascript, stackexchange-api

I'm currently playing with the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). My goal is to display a list of 5 last posts from a specific user.

I thought it would be easy, but well, I can't make it work...

Here's my try (client side, no auth) :

```
var apiURL = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts?order=desc&owner=enguerranws&site=stackoverflow';
    get(apiURL, getCB);
```

Where `get()` is is basic GET request and `getCB` a simple callback that should log the response.

This doesn't work, I get the last posts on SO from all users...

I looked into the API docs for couple of hours now, but I still don't know if it's possible and how to achieve it.

Comment: You can use `users/{ids}/posts` or `/me/posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the user in the URL, not in the parameters:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2054977/posts?order=desc&site=stackoverflow&pagesize=5

Comment: Well, thank you sir. Where can I find this point in the API doc ?

Comment: I know how to get the body of the post (with filter=withbody), but can I also get the title?

Comment: @enguerranws look [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-users) for the api on users and posts.

Comment: @Timo You should ask this as a question, but it's in the documentation you linked. Hint: You need to create a filter.